# Mysql docker container block while it's importing data (OSX)

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-compose

I'm working with two containers: server (php+apache) and mysql (image).
I'm using the latest docker version and OSX El Capitan.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
server:
    build: docker/images/server
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    links:
        - mysql
    tty: true
mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    volumes: 
        - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
```

When I'm importing my mysql dump, after 15-20 minutes the process blocks. I use this command to show a process bar:

```
pv database_dump.sql | mysql -uroot -proot test
```

The database_dump.sql is approximately 3.5GB.

Do I have to do some extra steps before starting to import my dump?

Thank you!

**Solution**

Finally, I had to create a new container with Ubuntu 14.04 and MySQL. I don't know why, the official MySQL container didn't work when I tried to import my database.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing using

```
cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb

Comment: Hi! Finally I created a new container with Ubuntu 14.04 and Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use MySQL Workbench and connect to your database URI and import the dump

Comment: I'm looking for a method to import my dump automatically through a bash script. Anyway, I have a dev environment via Vagrant and there isn't any problem to import my dump with the same command.

Comment: in that case, use this command "docker exec -i $CONTAINER_ID mysql -u $WORDPRESS_DB_USER -p$WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD $WORDPRESS_DB_NAME < backup.sql;"

Answer (score -1):

first, create a database;
then run the command:

$ pv data_file.sql | docker exec -i container_name mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD database_name

Comment: Please share more details. What have you changed? What makes you think that this works better than the original command?